# Route sql server traffic through firewall

Tags: linux, sql-server, iptables, linux-networking

We currently host our web application on multiple servers using Rackspace Auto Scale. This causes our outbound IP addresses to regularly change. At the same time we need to connect to an external sql server which is firewalled to a fix set of inbound IPs.

I currently have 1 fixed server that has access to the sql server, but the web servers do not have access.

I wanted to proxy the requests from the web tier through the server with IP access - (I have got around this before using HAProxy / squid, but this doesn't work for sql server as it is TDS)

I've seen a few different methods online to do this via iptables but am not getting a working solution.

What I have tried so far:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
#try 1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1433 -j DNAT --to-destination <destip>:1433
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d <destip> --dport 1433 -j SNAT --to-source <myip>
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d <myip> --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE


#try 2
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth2 --dport 1433 -j DNAT --to <destip>:1433
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE

#try 3
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d <myip> --dport 1433 -j DNAT --to <destip>:1433
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -d <myip> --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
```

Ideally I would like to send all traffic on the internal NIC (eth2) port 1433 to an external IP (would have to go through eth0) to the destination IP, port 1433.

Comment: Do you have static ports set on your SQL Server?  (SQL ports are dynamic by default in more recent versions.)

Comment: Yep. The connection from the proxy server to the SQL Server is set up.

Would just like to allow other servers to proxy through it